# Autofit a single column to fit text

Tags: tables

I have the following table and would like to have the first column (only) reduced so that the whole table is the same width as the text. I don't want to use `p{...cm}` because I want the table to fit the text automatically. However, I tried using it anyway, but found it doesn't work if I place it in `begin{tabular}{p{1cm}l|l|l|l|l|l}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow,blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{tabular}{ll|l|l|l|l|l|}
\cline{3-7}
& & \multicolumn{5}{|c|}{Going to ... dice matching}\\ \cline{3-7}
& & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{5}{*}{From ... dice matching}} & 1 & 720/7776 
& 5400/7776 & 1500/7776 & 150/7776 & 6/7776\\ \cline{2-7}
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} & 2 & & 120/216 & 80/216 & 15/216 & 1/216\\ \cline{2-7}
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} & 3 & & & 25/36 & 10/36 & 1/36\\ \cline{2-7}
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} & 4 & & & & 5/6 & 1/6\\ \cline{2-7}
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} & 5 & & & & & 1\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Where should I place `p{...cm}` for it to work?
How can I have the first column width automatically adjust to have the table fit the text?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Welcome! Take a look at `tabularx` and use the `X` column specifier for your first column. This will then be automatically adjusted to the width required to create a table of the specified total width.

Comment: Welcome. Your p column does not work because of those strange multicolumn commands. They are c not p.

Comment: @cfr . I did try to use `tabularx` like so: `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Xl|l|l|l|l|l}`, but it doesn't do anything to the first column and also removes lines at the bottom right corner of my table.

Comment: tabularx cannot remove your multicolumn statements!

Comment: You should also take a look at `booktabs` and consider following its advice for better looking tables.

Comment: @DannDope I was going to answer, but you already have a solution. (Not the one I had in mind, but it seems to do the job.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, by using `tabularx` you can set a width of the table and insert a `X` column. The latter is basically like `p`, butwith its width automatically set to the width needed to get a table with the given width. Here ist is used for the first column.

By changing the column declaration, so that there are vertical lines between all columns, the `\multicolumn`s for the last five lines can be removed. But the first two lines now need `\multicolumn`s to get rid of the unwanted vertical lines.

And finally `\multirow{5}{*}...` has to be changed to `\multirow{5}{=}...` so it takes the width of the column.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow,blindtext}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\cline{3-7}
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{Going to ... dice matching}\\ \cline{3-7}
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\ \hline
\multirow{5}{=}{From ... dice matching} & 1 & 720/7776 & 5400/7776 & 1500/7776 & 150/7776 & 6/7776\\ \cline{2-7}
 & 2 & & 120/216 & 80/216 & 15/216 & 1/216\\ \cline{2-7}
 & 3 & & & 25/36 & 10/36 & 1/36\\ \cline{2-7}
 & 4 & & & & 5/6 & 1/6\\ \cline{2-7}
 & 5 & & & & & 1\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @TeXnician They are there to get rid of the vertical lines on the left of these two rows. Is there a way to achieving this without them?

Comment: Sorry, just from looking at the code (without explanation) it looked wrong. But you're right then.